# Implement a web site using a pattern

Tags: architecture

I am trying to build a web site (something like a CMS). I have this architecture in mind:

A main skelton which acts as a framwork, and a collection of plug-ins or packages which are installed on the framework.

The problem is I don't know how to implement it, and I have no refrence to start with.
Can anyone please help me with this? Any help is higly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You havent specified what technology you are working on..but if its .net you could check out this article on using ASP.net MVC with MEF http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/04/21/ASPNET-MVC-and-the-Managed-Extensibility-Framework-(MEF).aspx

Comment: This question is very broad and definitely does not have a single valid answer. You should mark it community wiki

Comment: Can you provide your own insights for this question? It's been a while since you asked this question and I'm interested to know what are the most important aspects you learned from your own experience with writing a custom CMS.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by having a look at some of the open source CMS projects, for example dotnetnuke:http://www.dotnetnuke.com/

What you are trying to build sounds a lot like SharePoint with webparts for the packages installed on the framework. There is a "free" version of Sharepoint, that is included in the windows CAL.

Answer (score 0):

@InSane: Yes I am using ASP.NET - C#.

Here is more detail:
Suppose I have a website, which has an engine, this engine does not do anything special, except for managing and running some packages, or plug-ins.
The plug-ins or packages do different things, for example a package for user management, one for news management, one for reporting and so on.

I hope that clarifies a bit more.

Comment: FYI: add this sort of stuff as a "comment" or append it to your Question :)

Answer (score 0):

What's your biggest concern?  Having a clear idea of your priorities will help guide high-level decisions.

If the idea is that 3rd parties can make and add their own "apps" or modules then you'll need to think about the sorts of things they might want.

As far as patterns and principles go there's a whole raft you probably need to consider - more so that usual: Dependency Inversion, Stable Abstractions and Stable Dependency Principles all apply.

In the .Net world you can get a lot of mileage out of [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28VS.71%29.aspx), and Reflection can also help.

If you're after an example [this](http://morphfolia.codeplex.com/) might help: it's a wee Open Source .Net CMS I've been working (part time) on for the last few years.  I've also recently published "The Architecture" which this basically follows as well, which is [here](http://www.morphological.geek.nz/Architecture/5LA/default.aspx).